# For invertible matrices $A$ and $C$, prove or disprove that $(C^{-1}BAB^T + I)$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

For invertible matrices $A$ and $C$, ($B$ may or may not be invertible) prove or disprove that $(C^{-1}BAB^T + I)$ is invertible.

This problem came up while I was proving an equivalence. I couldn't find a way to prove that it is correct. Can you think of a way to prove it to be correct?

Comment: Err, don't you get the zero matrix if you take about $C=-I$, $B=A=I$?

Comment: @ ndrizza , you are not really an eagle. Yet, to comfort you, be aware that if you randomly choose (with a normal distribution) $A,B,C$ then, with probability $1$, $C$ is invertible and $C^{-1}BAB^T+I$  is invertible.

Comment: The question is simply dumb (i was really tired at that moment) and nobody will ever find the solution useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try, for example,  $B=C=I$, $A=-I$.

Comment: Ok, now you have that your equivalence relation may not be provable,@ndrizza. How about trying to find the smallest equivalence relation it contains? That might help you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see how I can constrain $A$, $B$ and $C$ further s.t. the equivalence holds.